# AttributeError while creating Vectory Layer with osgeo

Tags: python, gis

I am using this code:

```
import osgeo.osr
spatialReference = osgeo.osr.SpatialReference()
spatialReference.SetWellKnownGeogCS('WGS84')

import osgeo.ogr
driver = osgeo.ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile") 
dstFile = driver.CreateDataSource("boundingBoxes.shp") 
dstLayer = dstFile.CreateLayer("layer", spatialReference)
```

It is giving the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\saveborderinshapefile.py", line 8, in <module>    
dstLayer = dstFile.CreateLayer("layer", spatialReference)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'
```

Why is `dstFile` set to `None` in this code?

Comment: Perhaps the file `boundingBoxes.shp` wasn't found?

Comment: This looks like a question more suited to the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.